Anaconda Navigator on WSL: WARNING linux_scaling.get_scaling_factor_using_dbus:32
I am trying to use Anaconda Navigator at Ubuntu 22.04.03 (WSL), Windows 11.
When I type anaconda-navigator, it opens, but this message appears:
WARNING linux_scaling.get_scaling_factor_using_dbus:32
An exception occurred during fetching list of system display settings.


After a few seconds opened, the Navigator suddenly closes, and Killed appears on the terminal.

Same here. Can't find any working solutions.

This seems to be a scaling issue between WSL2 and the native windows environment.  I can get Spyder to run, but the mouse pointer is offset from the actual menu settings.  Make sure you have installed the MESA updates from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79151910/how-to-fix-errors-in-wsl-gui#:~:text=To%20fix%20this%2C%20clone%20the%20following%20repository%20and,powershell%3A%20If%20the%20repository%20is%20no%20longer%20available%3A

Also using a different x-window server, like MobaXterm seems to alleviate the problem.
