How to fix errors in WSL GUI
I just installed WSL2 and then installed nautilus.  When I run it I get:
MESA: error: ZINK: failed to choose pdev
libEGL warning: egl: failed to create dri2 screen
MESA: error: ZINK: failed to choose pdev
glx: failed to create drisw screen

** (org.gnome.Nautilus:1448): WARNING **: 01:40:31.937: Unable to get contents of the bookmarks file: Error opening file /home/amonra/.gtk-bookmarks: No such file or directory

** (org.gnome.Nautilus:1448): WARNING **: 01:40:31.938: Unable to get contents of the bookmarks file: Error opening file /home/amonra/.gtk-bookmarks: No such file or directory

then after longish wait nautilus appears.
How to fix all this please?

This seems to be an issue with Ubuntu 24.04 + WSLg where some files are not created for the ubuntu user (uid 1000) causing Wayland to fall back to X11.
WSLg bug reports: https://github.com/microsoft/wslg/issues/1250 and https://github.com/microsoft/wslg/issues/1244
To fix this, clone the following repository and follow the steps at Usage: https://github.com/viruscamp/wslg-links
Then run the following commands:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade

You might need to completely shutdown WSL from windows before the changes take effect. In powershell:
wsl --shutdown


If the repository is no longer available:

Create a new folder and enter it
Create a new file called wslg-tmp-x11.service with the following contents:

[Unit]
Description=Recreate WSLg X display file link after /tmp mounted
ConditionPathIsDirectory=/mnt/wslg/.X11-unix
Requires=tmp.mount
After=tmp.mount
Before=systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/chmod +t /mnt/wslg/.X11-unix
ExecStart=-/bin/rmdir /tmp/.X11-unix
ExecStart=/bin/ln -sf /mnt/wslg/.X11-unix /tmp/.X11-unix
#ExecStart=/bin/mount -m -o bind /mnt/wslg/.X11-unix /tmp/.X11-unix

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target


Create a new file called wslg-runtime-dir.service with the following contents:

[Unit]
Description=Recreate WSLg sockets files in $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
ConditionPathIsDirectory=/mnt/wslg/runtime-dir

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "ln -fs /mnt/wslg/runtime-dir/* "%t

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target


Run the following commands:

sudo cp wslg-tmp-x11.service /usr/lib/systemd/system/
sudo cp wslg-runtime-dir.service /usr/lib/systemd/user/

sudo systemctl --global disable pulseaudio.socket

sudo systemctl enable wslg-tmp-x11
sudo systemctl --global enable wslg-runtime-dir

All credit to avlec, viruscamp and czirok

Finally, some solution!
I've been struggling with that since they released 24.04 to WSL
I knew this version was very buggy on desktop, but it seems to be buggy on WSL side too
KompjoeFriek's solution works
Tho, on first starts nautilus takes ages to load up
I can't figure why, I just came with this solution :
alias nautilus="dbus-launch nautilus"

I added it to my .bashrc
